# Ordering by comments_count (counter cache) and created_at at the same time (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a counter cache called `comments_count`:

```
class AddCommentsCountToMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :microposts, :comments_count, :integer, :default => 0, :null => false
  end
end
```

to basically counts the number of comments for each micropost (Micropost model).
Now, this is how I order microposts by number of comments:

**controllers/microposts_controller.rb:**

```
  def index
    @microposts = Micropost.paginate(:page => params[:page],
                                     :per_page => 5).order('comments_count DESC')
  end
```

(I'm using the `will_paginate` gem)

Everything works as I want except that it is ordered `created_at ASC`. When there are two microposts with the same number of comments, the one created earlier is positioned first. I want the opposite, in other words, I want to order by **comments_count DESC** and **created_at DESC** at the same time.

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.order('comments_count DESC, created_at DESC')`

Comment: I think I feel dumb for asking this question.